# bash efficient file parsing

Tags: bash, performance, parsing, awk

I have log file in following format:

```
20:15:35 start opsdfslkdfflkjsdlkfjlsdkfj
20:17:21 lkjlkj lklkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj
.
.
.
20:34:11 end kljsdklasjdlaksjdasdasd
20:36:20 start lksadjlaskjdalksdj
.
.
etc
```

In result of parsing this file I would like to get time differences between subsequent `start` and `end` entries. For the sake of consistency it should be done in bash ( other log parsing was done in bash + plotting with gnuplot ). But reading file by redirecting it to `while` loop and then using e.g. `awk` to convert timestamp to seconds makes whole parsing extremely slow ( probably due to creating new subprocess per each line ).

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $string == *"start"* ]]
    then
        start=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
        echo $start
    fi
done <log.txt
```

Any ideas how this can be done efficiently in bash?

Comment: You're running awk once per line? That's insane. Run awk once to process the whole file, not once per individual line of input.

Comment: Or you could just do the math in native bash -- it's slower than doing it all with one instance of awk, but way faster than one instance of awk per line.

Comment: Amended, btw, to cover recognizing pairs and printing deltas -- in both native bash and awk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's slower than a pure `awk` instance would be, but in native bash, using only shell builtins:

```
while IFS=': ' read -r hr min sec content; do
  if [[ $content = *"start"* ]]; then
    start=$(( hr * 3600 + min * 60 + sec ))
    echo "$start"
  fi
done <log.txt
```

This will also run -- much faster -- in proper David Korn ksh. (Results, particularly performance results, will vary if using a ksh clone such as mksh rather than the legitimate article).

---

Alternately, for pure `awk`, you can avoid having any `while read` loop in bash at all:

```
awk -F: '/start/ { print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }' <log.txt
```

---

To implement the whole thing in bash (recognizing start/end pairs and printing the deltas) might look like this:

```
while IFS=': ' read -r hr min sec sigil rest; do
  case $sigil in
    start) start_sec=$(( hr * 3600 + min * 60 + sec )); end_sec= ;;
    end)   end_sec=$(( hr * 3600 + min * 60 + sec ))
           if [[ $start_sec ]]; then
             echo "$start_sec->$end_sec -- $(( end_sec - start_sec )) elapsed"
             start_sec=
           fi
           ;;
  esac
done <log.txt
```

...or, for the whole thing in awk:

```
awk -F: '
  /start/ { start=( ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 ) }
  /end/   { end=(   ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 );
            if (start) {
              print start " -> " end " -- " (end - start) " elapsed"
              start=0
            }
          }
' <log.txt
```

Comment: I'd recommend `/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+start[[:space:]]/` instead of `/start/` since we don't know what else is on the line.

Comment: Just wondering: why do you check `[[ $content = *"start"* ]]` instead of using regexp and say `[[ $content =~ .*start.* ]]`? Are they completely equivalent?

Comment: @fedorqui, for the regex I'd do `[[ $content =~ start ]]` -- regexes in bash aren't anchored unless one makes them explicitly so. Otherwise -- completely equivalent for these pairs of expressions in semantics, yes; in implementation, no. I'd have to benchmark to know if current releases have a performance delta worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny version, using a `sed` script and some compound-list of commands without a `while` loop; its execution time should be comparable to `awk`, still slower I believe: it needs to be confirmed with some testing.

Give a try to this to print time for the line with `start`:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9:]* start /{s/^\([0-9]*\):\([0-9]*\):\([0-9]*\) .*$/\1 60*\2+60*\3+p/p}' log.txt | dc
```

`dc` is a reverse-polish desk calculator.

`sed` is used to select the lines with `start` and make the string that is used with `dc`.

If your file always contains a pair of `start` and `end`, in this order, try this to calculate the time difference:

```
printf "%s %sr-p" $(sed -n '/^[0-9:]* \(start\|end\) /{s/^\([0-9]*\):\([0-9]*\):\([0-9]*\) .*$/\1 60*\2+60*\3+p/p}' log.txt | dc) | dc
```

`printf` is used to print **start** and **end** times by pair and generates another string to make a second `dc` calculate the difference.

Comment: I wouldn't call `dc` or `sed` "pure bash" -- neither is a shell builtin.

Comment: Ha ? yes, rereading this, it is more like an alternate solution to `awk`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the answer has been edited to remove `pure bash`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy also my answer is abstruse whereas the `while` loop is very clear.

Comment: Well, sure, but since you're explicitly writing this one to have fun rather than for clarity, I'm not going to complain about that. :)

Comment: cool thx ! stackoverflow is a cool site to play with `shell` :)